# I have form with same name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am try to send ajax form using jQuery in my html form with same names and deffirent values, but what happen is when I submit the form my ajax won't work and it will submit to `#`. someone can explain me why?

my HTML form:

```
<script src="lib/jquery/jquery.1.9.0.min.js"> </script>
<form name="Form" action="#" method="POST">
    <input name="idnum" type="hidden" value="somevaluehere1">
    <button type="submit">btn 1</button>
</form>

<form name="Form" action="#" method="POST">
    <input name="idnum" type="hidden" value="somevaluehere2">
    <button type="submit">btn 2</button>
</form>
```

this is my ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form[name=form]").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/post.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

sorry to my English guys

Comment: Named elements are unique and must remain that way. You can use a class though.

Comment: Names do not have to be unique....but they are case sensitive

Comment: 2\2 so pistols at dawn then ?

Comment: @Quentin True, yet that's a whole different thing. What I meant was that, when it comes to named POST variables, yes. Two elements cannot hold the same name. I.e.: `Name: <input type="text" name="name">` - `Surname: <input type="text" name="name">` - Radio/checkmarks count as one element/group; which is a sort of an exception to the rule, if I can say.

Comment: *The name attribute represents the form's name within the forms collection. The value must not be the empty string, and the value must be unique amongst the form elements in the forms collection that it is in, if any.* — http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-form-name (where it seems to be a new requirement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Form` is not the same as `form`. Your selector doesn't match the forms because attribute selector values are case sensitive.

Change `$("form[name=form]")` to `$("form[name=Form]")`.

You can prove this by comparing `alert($("form[name=form]").length);` to `alert($("form[name=Form]").length);`

Note, however, that [the name attribute for form elements should hold a unique value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-form-name) so you should switch to using the class attribute instead (then you can use the class selector (`form.Form`).

Comment: Well I went to make a fiddle for my answer, but you beat me to the draw http://jsfiddle.net/fM584/